# Spring Data JPA, Hibernate @Table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem:
My application has an MSSQL host in which there are 2 databases.
All my entities look at base number:

1. And one Entity should look at base
2. I can do this by specifying the base in the `@Table` parameter (schema = databasename.schema)

Is there any way to make the `@Table` (schema) parameter come from application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is [possible](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-global-catalog-schema). Look at the following properties:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="crm"/>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="analytics"/>
```

You can use the following properties in the spring boot `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_catalog=crm
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=analytics
```

Look also at the `@Table` annotation [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Table.html). When you set the schema attribute hibernate uses this specified schema, otherwise it is used user default schema that you can provide via `hibernate.default_schema`.

Also you can try to write your custom schema name resolver. As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_table_qualifying_options) for the `hibernate.schema_name_resolver` property:

> By default, Hibernate uses the [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#getSchemaNameResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#getSchemaNameResolver--). You can customize how the schema name is resolved by providing a custom implementation of the [SchemaNameResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/env/spi/SchemaNameResolver.html) interface.

Comment: In this case, all my Entities will start looking at this schema. And I only need one.

Comment: If you need it only in one place why you want set this globally?

Comment: I should be able to override these parameters if necessary through the config

Comment: You can set via `hibernate.default_schema` most used schema and then override it via `@Table (schema)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, only when redefining, use the variable from property

Comment: It simply does not work in this way. Look at the `@Table` annotation [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Table.html). When you set the `schema` attribute  hibernate uses this specified schema, otherwise it is used user default schema that you can provide via `hibernate.default_schema`

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can also customize the schema resolving by providing the custom implementation of the [SchemaNameResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/env/spi/SchemaNameResolver.html) interface. Maybe it will be more suitable for your needs.